# How to Parse XML using axios in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, xml, rss

My problem is I don't have an idea about parsing XML and getting display data in react-js jsx... Here is my RSS https://anchor.fm/s/75abc654/podcast/rss.I have already tried Axios,node-fetch,xml2js,react-RSS-feeder..etc. As far I researched no packages have a clear idea about it. Help me to display the data of each data in react... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I'm not a react developer, here's how you do it in vanilla JS.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
    let RSS_URL =  "https://anchor.fm/s/75abc654/podcast/rss"
    fetch(RSS_URL)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const items = data.querySelectorAll("item");
        let html = `<table>`;
        items.forEach(el => {
            let title = null;
            let link = null;
            let description = null;
            let image = null;

            // since we can't use querySelector to locate itunes:image namespaces, iterate through all child nodes, and pick off what we want.
            let itemNodes = el.querySelectorAll( "*" );
            itemNodes.forEach( item => {
                switch( item.nodeName ) {
                    case "title": 
                        title = item.textContent;
                        break;
                    case "description": 
                        description = item.textContent;
                        break;
                    case "link": 
                        link = item.innerHTML;
                        break;
                    case "itunes:image": 
                        image = item.getAttribute( "href" );
                        break;
                }
            });

            // Build the HTML

            html += `
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="${link}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">${title}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="${image}" width='100px'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${description}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            `;
        });
        html += "</table>";

        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```